# PDF Javascript Calculate number of Days between Dates

Tags: forms, pdf

I found a lot of script for JavaScript to calculate days between 2 dates... Here are my complications...

1 - I need to remove the weekends

2 - I need to set the value inside a cell in a PDF Form

This Javascript runs inside a PDF Form

So here how it works :

Cell #1 = FIRSTDAY

Cell #2 = LASTDAY

Cell #3 = TOTALDAYS

I would need to calculate the days difference between both days and removing the weekends... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the getting values from/setting values of the PDF form fields, but this function should calculate the number of weekdays between two dates:

```
var startDate = new Date('04/30/2012');
var endDate = new Date('05/31/2012');
var weekDaysElapsed = getWeekDaysElapsed (startDate, endDate);

function getWeekDaysElapsed (startDate, endDate) {
    var oneDayInMillis = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var elapsedDays = 0;
    if (startDate < endDate) {
        var day = startDate.getDay();
        if (day != 6 && day != 0) {   //6=Sat, 0=Sun
            elapsedDays = 1;
        }
        startDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + oneDayInMillis);
        return elapsedDays + getWeekDaysElapsed (startDate, endDate);
    }
    return elapsedDays;
}
```

Comment: Damn... I hope you will see this... I totally missed you answer... My biggest problem is the date format is "YYYY-MM-DD" .... I can't find how to parse it to give me how you did it